# az devops pipeline run yaml file stored locally?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-cli

I'm very interested in the options which open up for us with the [az devops cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest).

I'd like to be able to generate a yaml file locally and run it from local file by using the "az pipelines run" command.  is this possible?

it would allow for very fast iteration of pipeline creation. At present we are making updates to a yaml file in repo, committing, running and then reviewing (which isn't as smooth a process as it could be).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

There is a [suggestion under review on the Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366517/ability-to-test-yaml-builds-locally.html).

Comment: there was an issue on GH somewhere about this, afair. probably better to track it there